# SQL Server Management Studio Activity Monitor: What is the unexpected "SQL" at the top of the 'Last Transact-SQL command batch"

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

My C# program submits multiple `SELECT` queries to a SQL Server instance on a remote server. I'm trying to track down a query problem using SQL Server Mgmt Studio Activity Monitor on the remote server. The text in the screen shot was taken from the `Last Transact-SQL command batch` dialog that appeared when I right-clicked on the process representing my failed SQL query in the activity monitor (The query causes the server to stop responding).

My question is this: The text at the top of the window `(@SearchString nvarchar(8))` is unexpected. Where did it come from? `@SearchString` is the name of a C# variable that I use in my program for a SQL parameter, but the `SELECT` statements that I compose and send from my program do not explicitly include `(@SearchString nvarchar(8))` as shown in the activity monitor. Is my SQL Server instance inserting this on the remote server side for some reason?

p.s. I think trying to convert the VARBINARY contentData column to NVARCHAR is what is probably causing my query to hang

[image: Text copied from SQL activity monitor Last Transact-SQL command batch dialog]

Comment: It's likely being added by the tool to assist with running the queries below. `@SearchString` is a variable used in the queries, so the tool is simply declaring it for you using the parameterized queries syntax.

Comment: @DanWilson Well, dang - that makes sense! I wasn't thinking of it from the perspective of the server. Please morph this into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is running parameterized queries. When viewing the queries for the process using the activity monitor, any parameters are declared using the parameterized queries syntax, namely `(@SearchString nvarchar(8))`.

This is beneficial as 1) information when viewing the queries and 2) if you would like to run the queries outside of the application.

The script can be found using the `sys.dm_exec_sql_text()` table-valued function and passing the SQL handle for the connection.

Below is a query that approximates the data found in the activity monitor tool. Source: [Google web cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yunJkibA6o0J:geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2013/03/20/152474.aspx+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

```
SELECT 
   SessionId    = s.session_id, 
   UserProcess  = CONVERT(CHAR(1), s.is_user_process),
   LoginInfo    = s.login_name,   
   DbInstance   = ISNULL(db_name(r.database_id), N''), 
   TaskState    = ISNULL(t.task_state, N''), 
   Command      = ISNULL(r.command, N''), 
   App            = ISNULL(s.program_name, N''), 
   WaitTime_ms  = ISNULL(w.wait_duration_ms, 0),
   WaitType     = ISNULL(w.wait_type, N''),
   WaitResource = ISNULL(w.resource_description, N''), 
   BlockBy        = ISNULL(CONVERT (varchar, w.blocking_session_id), ''),
   HeadBlocker  = 
        CASE 
            -- session has active request; is blocked; blocking others
            WHEN r2.session_id IS NOT NULL AND r.blocking_session_id = 0 THEN '1' 
            -- session idle; has an open tran; blocking others
            WHEN r.session_id IS NULL THEN '1' 
            ELSE ''
        END, 
   TotalCPU_ms        = s.cpu_time, 
   TotalPhyIO_mb    = (s.reads + s.writes) * 8 / 1024, 
   MemUsage_kb        = s.memory_usage * 8192 / 1024, 
   OpenTrans        = ISNULL(r.open_transaction_count,0), 
   LoginTime        = s.login_time, 
   LastReqStartTime = s.last_request_start_time,
   HostName            = ISNULL(s.host_name, N''),
   NetworkAddr        = ISNULL(c.client_net_address, N''), 
   ExecContext        = ISNULL(t.exec_context_id, 0),
   ReqId            = ISNULL(r.request_id, 0),
   WorkLoadGrp        = N'',
   LastCommandBatch = (select text from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle)) 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c ON (s.session_id = c.session_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r ON (s.session_id = r.session_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks t ON (r.session_id = t.session_id AND r.request_id = t.request_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    -- Using row_number to select longest wait for each thread, 
    -- should be representative of other wait relationships if thread has multiple involvements. 
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY waiting_task_address ORDER BY wait_duration_ms DESC) AS row_num
    FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks 
) w ON (t.task_address = w.waiting_task_address) AND w.row_num = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r2 ON (r.session_id = r2.blocking_session_id)
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) as st

WHERE s.session_Id > 50                         -- ignore anything pertaining to the system spids.

AND s.session_Id NOT IN (@@SPID)     -- let's avoid our own query! :)
```